# my program is leaking with resource owned by boost::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, boost, memory-leaks, stdmap

I can't see why my program is leaking, maybe you can spot it.

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr < std::string >   StringPtr;
typedef std::pair < HWND, StringPtr >       WMapPair; 
typedef std::map  < HWND, StringPtr >       WindowMap;

// this callback populates the WindowMap (m_Windows) by adding a WMapPair each time
BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsCallback( HWND hWnd )
{
    // adds this window to the WindowMap, along with its title text

    BOOL        bRetVal         = FALSE;
    int         nTextLen        = 0;
    char*       sWindowText     = NULL;     

    if( ! ::IsWindow( hWnd ) )
        return FALSE;

    nTextLen = GetWindowTextLength( hWnd );
    if( ! nTextLen )
        return TRUE;

    sWindowText = new char[nTextLen + 1];
    if( sWindowText )
    {
        GetWindowTextA( hWnd, sWindowText, nTextLen );

        m_Windows.insert( WMapPair(hWnd, StringPtr(new std::string(sWindowText))) );

        delete [] sWindowText;

        sWindowText = NULL;
        bRetVal     = TRUE;
    }

    return bRetVal;
}
```

My class contains this WindowMap population works correctly, but teardown doesn't seem to be working correctly.  The class destructor calls this function to clear the map - which should release the shared_ptr's, thereby deleting them, right? :)

```
void EraseList()
{       
    m_Windows.clear();  
}
```

I'd love to know what I'm missing - all the StringPtr's are leaking.

***UPDATE***
RE the comment that the "StringPtr(new std::string(sWindowText)))" was stylistically wrong, I made the suggested change, as below, but, the memory leak is still there.

```
BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsCallback( HWND hWnd )
{
    // adds this window to the WindowMap, along with its title text

    BOOL        bRetVal         = FALSE;
    int         nTextLen        = 0;
    char*       sWindowText     = NULL;     
    StringPtr   strPtr;     

    if( ! ::IsWindow( hWnd ) )
        return FALSE;

    nTextLen = GetWindowTextLength( hWnd );
    if( ! nTextLen )
        return TRUE;

    sWindowText = new char[nTextLen + 1];
    if( sWindowText )
    {
        GetWindowTextA( hWnd, sWindowText, nTextLen );

        strPtr = StringPtr(new std::string(sWindowText));

        m_Windows.insert( WMapPair(hWnd, strPtr) );

        delete [] sWindowText;

        sWindowText = NULL;
        bRetVal     = TRUE;
    }

    return bRetVal;
}
```

***Conclusion***
I've gone with the suggestion of ditching StringPtr and using make_pair(hWnd, std::string()) and have sidestepped the issue that way.

Comment: I don't see an obvious cause of the leak.  (I'm sure others will find it.)  However, I think you are making things more complicated than need-be: std::string will automatically clean up its resources when its destructor is called.  Why not simply use a map of std::map  < HWND, std::string >?

Comment: This is stylistically wrong:  `StringPtr(new std::string(sWindowText))`.  Every new dynamically allocated object should be initially owned by a **named** smart pointer.  For more, read [the Boost `shared_ptr` best practices](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#BestPractices).  Also, consider using a `std::vector<char>` instead of dynamically allocating the array yourself.  I don't think either of these are the cause of your specific problem, though.

Comment: Wich version of wich compiler?

Comment: @Eric Pi: the callback would allocate the std::string on the stack, so as soon as the callback returned, the std::string would be released, hence the need for a heap allocated string.

Comment: @James McNellis, thanks for the link, I've made the update, but it made no difference (I noted you'd said that it wasn't the cause of my problem though).  I'll look at using an std::vector<char> once I get my memory leak issue sorted!

Comment: @freefallr:  No; when you have a `std::map<int, std::string> m;` and you do a `m.insert(std::make_pair(0, std::string("Hello World")));`, a copy of the temporary `std::string("Hello World")` is inserted into the `std::map`.

Comment: sWindowText: can never be NULL. Don't bother checking. Also don't new/delete objects use an appropriate object that does it for you (like in this case a string). Also curious why you even need to dynamically allocate the string. Just create and copy into the map.

Comment: @Martin I suppose its a lazy check for memory allocation failure.  I dynamically allocate the string because its length isn't known until runtime and its easy to do so.  I am interested in learning how to supply a vector of char as an argument to GetWindowTextA(), but it is second to my problem of the memory leak when deallocating the map

Comment: @Martin - I just checked, according to MSDN, the new operator can fail and return zero, so my check was valid.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kewsb8ba.aspx - "If unsuccessful, new returns zero or throws an exception"

Comment: @James - I take your point RE using an std::string instead of a boost::shared_ptr < std::string >.  I'd guess my (incorrect) conclusion might be an easy one to make - that a stack allocated string might be meaningless after the stack unwinds; I didn't know it'd survive when added to a map.  I'm going to go with that solution, as I've been tearing my hair out on this issue for too long now!

Comment: @James - how about an example of how to use a vector of char as the 2nd argument to GetWindowText (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633520(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a circular reference? That is what boost::weak_ptr is for.

Comment: You need to resize the vector to be of sufficient size then you can get a pointer to its initial element using `&v[0]`.  For example:  `std::vector<TCHAR> v(nTextLen + 1); GetWindowText(hWnd, &v[0], nTextLen);`

Comment: @freefallr - You are not using the `operator new` you linked to, but the `new` operator (a diffent thing, despite the similar name). Read here [The new and delete operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kftdy56f.aspx) instead.

Comment: @Bo Persson - that's strange.  I had a look at your link.  It takes you to a page that links straight back to my link for the new operator!!!

Comment: @freefallr - When you write `new x` in your program, that is the `new` operator I linked to. It says there that it will throw a `std::bad_alloc` if it fails.

Comment: I don't dispute that it can throw an std::bad_alloc when it fails.  However, the page I linked to (and the page you also, indirectly linked to) states that "If unsuccessful, new returns zero or throws an exception".  So it _can_ do either.

Comment: @Sam Miller - in any case, I just went with James McNellis's suggestion of std::make_pair(hWnd, std::string(bleh))

Comment: @freefallr - No it cannot!  :-)  The page you link to is for `operator new` which is an operator you can override to have some special memory allocation for a type. My page is about the `new` in a statment like `new x`. Even though they both use the word `new`, they mean different things. And I can assure you that `new x` will not return NULL, it will throw an exception.

Comment: I'm quoting the MSDN page for "new operator" - If unsuccessful, new returns zero or throws an exception; see "The new and delete Operators" for more information.  The new and delete Operators link takes you to your page.  The MSDN documentation is definitely misleading in this case.  I'll maybe look it up in Windows via C/C++ or similar...

Comment: @freefallr: `new` will return 0 if you compile with exceptions turned off. As long as you compile with exceptions turned on (and if you don't, don't use the STL), it will *always* throw in case it cannot allocate.

Comment: @freefallr: new either works successfully or throws an exception. If you use the no-throw version it may return NULL but you are not using this.  Checking for NULL is not only pointless it makes the code harder to read and maintain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not going to answer your question (as I can;t see any problems) but a couple of points:

```
typedef std::map  < HWND, std::string >     WindowMap;
typedef WindowMap::value_type               WMapPair;    // In the future it may not be a pair.
                                                         // Or you may change the type of WindowMap
                                                         // Make it so the value is based on the container.
                                                         // Done automatically.

// this callback populates the WindowMap (m_Windows) by adding a WMapPair each time
BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsCallback( HWND hWnd )
{
    // adds this window to the WindowMap, along with its title text

    // Declare variables at there first usage point.
    // There is no need to clutter the top of the function 
    // With usless variables that may never be used.

    if( ! ::IsWindow( hWnd ) )
        return FALSE;

    int nTextLen = GetWindowTextLength( hWnd );
    if( ! nTextLen )
        return TRUE;

    // Use a vector. Dynamically allocating memory is dangerious and not
    // exception safe (unless you use a smart pointer (or in this case a container))
    std::vector<char>  sWindowText(nTextLen + 1);
    GetWindowTextA( hWnd, &sWindowText[0], nTextLen );

    // No need for shared pointers. Just put the string in the map.
    m_Windows.insert( WMapPair(hWnd, std::string(sWindowText.begin(),
                                                 sWindowText.begin()+ nTextLen)));

    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: yeah, I went with this kind of approach (e.g. James' suggestion as stated earlier)

Answer (score 2):

There was (is?) a bug in VS2010 `std::vector<>` implementation causing memory to leak under certain circumstances (see [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/596565/memory-leak-with-std-vector-std-string-insert-using-const-std-string)). AFAIK, it has been fixed in VS2010 SP1, but I'm not 100% positive.

Comment: thanks for the heads up, I wasn't aware of that!  I do have VS2010 SP1 installed, and my problem seems to be with a map rather than with a vector.

Comment: Nothing prevents `map` from using `vector` internally.

Comment: I can confirm that this was fixed in SP1.

Answer (score 0):

I've gone with James' suggestion:

@freefallr: No; when you have a std::map m; and you do a m.insert(std::make_pair(0, std::string("Hello World")));, a copy of the temporary std::string("Hello World") is inserted into the std::map. – James McNellis